# Wacom Bamboo MTE-450 on 12.10 LTS

Tags: wacom, bamboo

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying to get my Wacom Tablet (MTE-450) working.  I have seen other threads that refer to methods of installing drivers for CTH or CTL models.  Is this method the same for my model?

I updated to 12.10 as suggested by another user, but still no luck.  The tablet is still not recognized.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of Ubuntu? I know that the graphics tablet drivers were significantly upgraded in 12.10.

Comment: Updated to 12.10 and still nothing.  The tablet is not recognized in the "Wacom Graphics Manager" window either.  This is after restarting and trying all USB ports.